# xrandr with 4 screens and extend configuration

Tags: xubuntu, screen, xrandr, debian, gnu

I have 4 screens and i want to have an extend configuration :

4x1 => 7920x1080

I config an video wall menu board and i want to have 1 display on ALL screen

How do this setup ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so :) i have found how to do this WALL :)

Use this command :

```
xrandr --setmonitor WALL auto screen1,screen2,screen3,screen4
```

:) and after that use configuration you want with

```
arandr
```

Regards